# How can I align buttons to the center of the navbar

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile to create this navbar but I can't align the buttons to the center.

Here is my code:

```
<footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <nav data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-audio ui-btn-icon-notext">Record</a></li>
                <li><a href="#load" class="ui-btn ui-icon-cloud ui-btn-icon-notext">Upload</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-recycle ui-btn-icon-notext">Refresh</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext">Clear</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
</footer>
```

I have tried with `data-grid="c"` but it's not working.

Any idea?

I haven't add any CSS style to this project

This is the compiled jQuery Mobile:

Block (each block inside the navbar):

```
.ui-grid-c > .ui-block-a, .ui-grid-c > .ui-block-b, .ui-grid-c > .ui-block-c, .ui-grid-c > .ui-block-d {
width: 25%;
}

ul.ui-grid-a, ul.ui-grid-b, ul.ui-grid-c, ul.ui-grid-d, ul.ui-grid-solo, li.ui-block-a, li.ui-block-b, li.ui-block-c, li.ui-block-d, li.ui-block-e {
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}

.ui-block-a {
clear: left;
}

.ui-block-a, .ui-block-b, .ui-block-c, .ui-block-d, .ui-block-e {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
float: left;
min-height: 1px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

li {
display: list-item;
text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}

.ui-navbar ul {
list-style: none;
}

ul.ui-grid-a, ul.ui-grid-b, ul.ui-grid-c, ul.ui-grid-d, ul.ui-grid-solo, li.ui-block-a, li.ui-block-b, li.ui-block-c, li.ui-block-d, li.ui-block-e {
list-style: none;
}

ul, menu, dir {
list-style-type: disc;
}

.ui-bar-b, .ui-page-theme-b .ui-bar-inherit, html .ui-bar-b .ui-bar-inherit, html .ui-body-b .ui-bar-inherit, html body .ui-group-theme-b .ui-bar-inherit {
color: #fff /*{b-bar-color}*/;
text-shadow: 0 /*{b-bar-shadow-x}*/ 1px /*{b-bar-shadow-y}*/ 0 /*{b-bar-shadow-radius}*/ #111 /*{b-bar-shadow-color}*/;
font-weight: bold;
}

.ui-overlay-a, .ui-page-theme-a, .ui-page-theme-a .ui-panel-wrapper {
color: #333 /*{a-page-color}*/;
text-shadow: 0 /*{a-page-shadow-x}*/ 1px /*{a-page-shadow-y}*/ 0 /*{a-page-shadow-radius}*/ #f3f3f3 /*{a-page-shadow-color}*/;
}

.ui-overlay-a, .ui-page-theme-a, .ui-page-theme-a .ui-panel-wrapper {
color: #333 /*{a-page-color}*/;
text-shadow: 0 /*{a-page-shadow-x}*/ 1px /*{a-page-shadow-y}*/ 0 /*{a-page-shadow-radius}*/ #f3f3f3 /*{a-page-shadow-color}*/;
}

body, input, select, textarea, button, .ui-btn {
font-size: 1em;
line-height: 1.3;
font-family: sans-serif /*{global-font-family}*/;
}
```

Icon

```
.ui-btn-icon-notext:after, .ui-btn-icon-top:after, .ui-btn-icon-bottom:after {
left: 50%;
margin-left: -11px;
}

.ui-btn-icon-notext:after, .ui-btn-icon-left:after, .ui-btn-icon-right:after {
top: 50%;
margin-top: -11px;
}

.ui-btn-icon-left:after, .ui-btn-icon-right:after, .ui-btn-icon-top:after, .ui-btn-icon-bottom:after, .ui-btn-icon-notext:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
display: block;
width: 22px;
height: 22px;
}

.ui-btn-icon-left:after, .ui-btn-icon-right:after, .ui-btn-icon-top:after, .ui-btn-icon-bottom:after, .ui-btn-icon-notext:after {
background-color: #666 /*{global-icon-color}*/;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3) /*{global-icon-disc}*/;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-border-radius: 1em;
border-radius: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Show us the CSS you have tried so far.

Comment: I haven't put any CSS yet. But I have tried `display: inline-block` and or `margin-left: 10px;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is, to force button inside each block to fill width completely.

```
.ui-navbar li a {
  width: 100% !important;    
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2KbSP/)**

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at using [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

> The vertical-align CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an
>   inline or table-cell box.

Try:

```
a.ui-btn{
   vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Although this is on the assumption you dont have other style settings which may interfere, its hard to say without having your CSS. You may need to also set `margin:0;` or remove any `padding`from the containing `li`

Comment: It didn't worked any. I have updated the code compiled CSS from Developer Tools

Answer (score 0):

Try `margin: 0 auto` in your css

Comment: It didn't work neither. I have updated the code compiled CSS from Developer Tools